# How to retrieve returned JS functions values and pass it in Flask

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I have the following dropdown menus which their values are retuned from MongoDB.

**HTML**

```
<form>
  <div class="answer1wrap">
    <select id="mySelect1">
        <option value="void">Choose your answer</option>
        {% for row in rows %}
            <option value="{{row}}">{{row}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
  <select id="mySelect2">
       <option value="void">Choose your answer</option>
        {% for row in rows %}
            <option value="{{row}}">{{row}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
<button class="btn btn-default" id="checkbtn" onclick="answers_1();answers_2();" type="button"><span    class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span> Check answers</button>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
  function answers_1() {
     var select = document.getElementById("mySelect1");
     var answer = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
     return answer;
   }
   function answers_2() {
      var select = document.getElementById("mySelect2");
      var answer = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
      return answer;
   }
</script>
```

I aim to use what both JS functions return (ObjectID), then using them to get a particular data in that collection.

I have the following function, where `key_1` and `key_2` are the values returned from the JS functions, but somehow I cannot make it work.

```py
@app.route("/distance_object", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def distance_object():
    row_object = []
    cursor = object_collection.find({}, {"_id": 1})
    for document in cursor:
        row_object.append(document['_id'])
    input_1 = object_collection.find({"_id": ObjectId(key_1)}, {"x_input": 2})
    input_2 = object_collection.find({"_id": ObjectId(key_2)}, {"x_input": 2})
    return render_template("distance.html", rows=row_object)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like that function in JS

```
<script>
  function answers_1() {
     var select = document.getElementById("mySelect1");
     return select.value;
   }
   function answers_2() {
      var select = document.getElementById("mySelect2");
      return select.value;
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! but, I have written the same JS function that does the same process as you answered.